# Как подключить jetty к проекту?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty

Закачал с гитхаба проект с сервлетами. Запускаю. А тут раз - не существует сервер  `jetty`! Я в растерянности. Дело в том, что я также качал другой проект (с импортом таких же пакетов) и он запускался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: как подключить соответствующие пакеты?

Comment: Автоматический сборщик проекта не используете, я правильно понял?

Comment: @cadmy а он тут разве нужен? Дергалось с гитхаба. Хотелось сие запустить сначала из IDE

Comment: Он опционален :) Просто с ним таких проблем не возникает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Скачиваете jar
2. В идее заходите в `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` ->
   нажимаете на плюсик -> указываете скаченный jar

Comment: Спасибо тебе родной! Век помнить буду.

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.3.0.M1/jetty-server-9.3.0.M1.jar Вот, кстати, ссылка на jetty.server